# How can I use the ".title() command to read a text file and capitalize every word in the file?

Tags: python, command, title

My program has to create another file by the name "CTL.py" that has every word in the text file capital and every sentence ending with "#". I have to use the title(). There are 131 lines in my text file. My thought process is to use a loop to read and capitalize every letter in the text and some how add '#' after a readline() command. Any ideas on how to go about this?

```
def main():

    myFile = open('/Users/Chandlers_Mac/Downloads/Lab9-2.txt', 'r')
    for i in range(131):
        data = myFile.read()
        data.title()
        print(data, end = '')

#end main   
main()
```

Comment: So.. what's your question? How to write that into a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate line by line, title, strip the newline then add a `#`, a newline back and write the line to the new file:

```
with open('/Users/Chandlers_Mac/Downloads/Lab9-2.txt') as f,open("CTL.py", "w") as out:
    for line in f:
        out.write(line.title().rstrip()+"#\n")
```

In relation to your own code:

```
data.title()
```

does nothing as you don't reassign data, you would need `data = data.title()`, calling title create a new string it does not modify the original,also you don't need range and even if you did after the first call to `.read()` the iterator would be exhausted so the next 130 calls would do nothing. There are much better ways but if you did want to get 131 lines from a file using that method you would call `next(myFile)` or `myFile.readline()` not read as that reads the whole file at once.